# cfchart data to display drive details indivisually

Tags: coldfusion

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<cfhttp method="Get"
 url="http://localhost:90/myweb/xmlwork/xmlfile.cfm">

<cfoutput>
  #cfhttp.filecontent#
</cfoutput>
<br>
<br><br><br>
<!---<cffile action="read" file="http://localhost:90/myweb/xmlfile.cfm" variable="myxml">--->
<cfset mydoc = XmlParse(cfhttp.filecontent)>
<cfset dd = mydoc.StorageList.XmlChildren>
<cfset size = ArrayLen(dd)>
<cfoutput>
Number of Drive = #size#
<br>
</cfoutput>
<br>

<cfset myquery = QueryNew("DriveName,TotalSpace,FreeSpace") >

<cfset temp = QueryAddRow(myquery, #size#)>
<cfloop index="i" from = "1" to = #size#>
  <cfset temp = QuerySetCell(myquery, "DriveName", 
    #mydoc.StorageList.DriveDetails[i].DriveName.XmlText#, #i#)>
  <cfset temp = QuerySetCell(myquery, "TotalSpace", 
    #mydoc.StorageList.DriveDetails[i].TotalSpace.XmlText#, #i#)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(myquery, "FreeSpace", 
    #mydoc.StorageList.DriveDetails[i].FreeSpace.XmlText#, #i#)>
</cfloop>

Contents of the: <br>
<cfdump var=#myquery#>
<br><cfloop index="i" from = "1" to = #size#>
<cfchart format="flash"  show3d="true" chartwidth="300" chartheight="300" >
            <cfchartseries type="pie">
             <cfloop query="myquery">
  <cfchartdata item="#TotalSpace#" value="#FreeSpace#"> 
                </cfloop>
            </cfchartseries>
        </cfchart>
</cfloop>


<!---<cfloop index="i" from = "1" to = #size#>
  <cfchart>
<cfchartseries 
    type="pie" 

    query="myquery" 
    valueColumn="TotalSpace" 
    itemColumn="FreePace"/>
</cfchart>
</cfloop>--->
</body>
</html>
```

i have  this code for chart display,but it showing in one chart i want to display this in indivisual chart

Answer (score 0):

Instead of constructing a query and using it to display in your chartseries, use a chartseries with [cfchartdata](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-792d.html) to add the appropriate data to the chart.